# Compare elements between them and get the keys of common values

Tags: c++, algorithm, key, containers, matching

I have pairs of data, key and value in two different collections.  I need compare the values of both collections, and create a collection containing the pairs of the keys for values that are equal.

For example, with the following dataset:

```
      Vals
Key Col1 Col2
1    4     5
2    6     9
4    8     4
6    10    10
```

the common values would be 4 and 10.  So he idea is get a new collection with the pairs, in this case (key col1, key col2) {{1, 4}, {6, 6}}

I need a fastest way to do this, every collection can have easly 100k of data, and iterating with a for-loop is too slow, I try with vector.

Both collection do not necessarily have the same keys (like map), and the data could be something else than an int (I use binary data, and usually the keys are ints (unsinged long).

Here is my example code (very very slow code):

```
struct p {
    unsigned long int p1;
    unsigned long int p2;
};

vector<int> table1 = tables1(n); /* bigger n -> more samples */
vector<int> table2 = tables2(n); /* n = 10000 generate 150k per table */

vector<p> common;

for (unsigned long int i = 0;i < table1.size(); i++) {
    for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < table2.size(); j++) {
        if (table1[i] == table2[j]) {common.push_back ({i, j};}
    }
}
```

Is there a way maybe with map, set, or something to do this faster?
(i'm starting with c++)

Comment: create two maps. A  maps from key to col1, B from key to col2. then just compare A[key] == B[key] if key  exists in both

Comment: you mean do the same with map instead vector?, in that case i don't think will be faster, this algorithm is really slow....

Comment: It should be O(n lgn) rather than O(n^2)

Comment: Testing it, is still very slow..., compare maps or vectors.....

Comment: You're not doing it right, then. The correct algorithm will iterate over both maps, simultaneously, instead of iterating over the first one, and then checking the second map, each time. This is wrong. You need to iterate over both maps at the same time. If you still have questions, you should ask your instructor for help, the one who gave you this assignment. This is what instructors are paid to do, to help students with their homework assignments.

Comment: What you can do is used an unordered_map when the data is being initially inserted. If the key doesnt exists, add. If the key already exists, compare if the new values is diff from the current. This should still run in O(n lgn), with smaller constant since the map grows as its added. This will most likely still be slow since there is a lot of data, how much slower/faster is the key. What times are you getting on your benchmarks?

Answer (score 2):

In fact you compare all the values between them and want to know the keys of that value in each collection.

In this case, I'd suggest to simply invert the key and the value in each map.  This would lead to the following struvture:

```
      Vals
RevKey1 RevVal1 RevKey2 RevVal2
4       1         5     1
6       2         9     2
8       4         4     4
10      6        10     6
```

You'd then just have to iterate over the first map, and look for the same key in the second map:

```
map<int,int> col1;
map<int,int> col2;
map<int,pair<int,int>> common ; 
...
for (auto& x: col1) {
    auto y= col2.find(x.first); 
    if (y!=col2.end()) 
        common[x.first]=make_pair(x.second,y->second);
}
cout<<"Result:"<<endl;
for (auto& x:common ) 
    cout << x.first << "<-" << x.second.first << " in col1 and " <<x.second.second << " in col2"<<endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/cLgfoG)

*Remark: I let you as an exercise the inversion of the mapping relation expressed in existing maps.  I also let you extend this algorithm to cope with multimaps, in case of several keys having the same value.*

Comment: Why do you need two maps?

Comment: @PaulSanders I used maps because OP has data that shows that the keys are not consecutive.  For example there is no key 3.  With `vector<int>` you can't represent this. Also, OP suggests that data could be different from integer, which is not the problem in case of maps.

Comment: Thx for your answare, seems there is not a built-in function for this (thinking in tables of different length), and this would be better, i know how invert the maps, but use multimap is new for me, that will be my exercise, Thx helping :D

Answer (score 0):

The following (very simple) code seems to cut the mustard:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct p
{
    p (int p1, int p2) : p1 (p1), p2 (p2) { }
    int p1;
    int p2;
};

std::vector<int> table1;
std::vector<int> table2;
std::vector<p> common;

#define N   100000

int main ()
{
    table1.reserve (N);
    table2.reserve (N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        table1.emplace_back (rand ());

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        table2.emplace_back (rand ());

    std::map <int, int> map1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        map1 [table1 [i]] = i;

    common.reserve (N);

    int n = table2.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        auto f = map1.find (table2 [i]);
        if (f != map1.end ())
            common.emplace_back (i, f->second);
    }

    for (auto x : common)
       std::cout << x.p1 << ", " << x.p2 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
12727, 93810
12766, 48493
16044, 71990
43202, 35849
46218, 81007
82512, 70112
98740, 72244
```

Note the use of `reserve` and `emplace_back` for the vectors.

Run it at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zG1PyWYjNcKEbuvJ)

I tried increasing N to 1000000 and it still worked.  An unordered (hashed) map might be faster.